# Complete site rip of a website using wget

Tags: macros, wget

I am attempting to perform a complete site rip of a website, I know where the streamed videos locations are however getting the process to run as efficiently and productively is proving difficult.

First problem is logging in:

I have googled many times on logging in just as a browser would. Say I want to login to a pay website that allows me access and the login button is on the mainpage with a I think javascript popup window it does not take me to a /login/ at the end of url I tried using cookies but no luck. any assistance there would be great.

next step I need to change the user agent to android kitkat I assumed it would be `--user-agent=""User-Agent:Android KitKat` is that right? reason for this is if I fool the website into thinking I am not on the computer it will let me save video as since the site uses brightcove.com to stream its content.

next I need to tell it specifically to go through all the pages and download only .mp4 files. (is there a way for it to do some sort of right click and save as on all the streamed videos that it picks up?) sorry this might be a tad confusing. this may also be a bit farfetched but any program or way to copy the video title that is underneath the stream and paste it into the file to rename it once it has downloaded? i doubt it but if there is let me know :)

and while not related to this certain project how would I get wget to go through say www.@@@@@.com/download/1/file/mp4 all the way to www.@@@@@.com/download/1000000/file/mp4 offline browser had a url macro I could use but I have no idea how to do that with wget so that would be neat to know.